# Symfony2 error with adding new entities using collection prototype

Tags: forms, symfony, collections, prototype

I have used the exact functionality before without any issues. I have been looking for hours now and just can't figure out what's wrong. Hopefully you could help me out! Any help would be appreciated.

So I have the following entities:

LocationBike:

```
class LocationBike extends TranslatableEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\LocationBikeAccessory", mappedBy="locationBike", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    protected $accessorys;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->accessorys = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add bike accessory.
     *
     * @param LocationBikeAccessory $bike
     *
     * @return LocationBike
     */
    public function addAccessory(LocationBikeAccessory $accessory = null)
    {
        $accessory->setLocationBike($this);
        $this->accessorys[] = $accessory;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove bike accessory.
     *
     * @param LocationBikeAccessory
     */
    public function removeAccessory(LocationBikeAccessory $accessory)
    {
        $this->accessorys->removeElement($accessory);
    }

    /**
     * Get accessorys.
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getAccessorys()
    {
        return $this->accessorys;
    }
}
```

LocationBikeAccessory:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_location_bike_accessory")
 */
class LocationBikeAccessory
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\LocationBike", inversedBy="accessorys", cascade={"persist"})
     **/
    protected $locationBike;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Accessory", cascade={"persist"})
     **/
    protected $accessory;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $price;

    /**
     * Get id.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set location bike.
     *
     * @param LocationBike $bike
     */
    public function setLocationBike(LocationBike $bike)
    {
        $this->locationBike = $bike;
    }

    /**
     * Get location bike.
     *
     * @return LocationBike $bike
     */
    public function getLocationBike()
    {
        return $this->locationBike;
    }

    /**
     * Set accessory.
     *
     * @param Accessory $accessory
     */
    public function setAccessory(Accessory $accessory)
    {
        $this->accessory = $accessory;
    }

    /**
     * Get specification.
     *
     * @return Accessory $accessory
     */
    public function getAccessory()
    {
        return $this->accessory;
    }

    /**
     * Set price.
     *
     * @param float $price
     *
     * @return LocationBikeAccessory
     */
    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get price.
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }
}
```

The form types look like this:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

/**
 * LocationBike form.
 */
class LocationBikeType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * Build form.
     *
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ///
            ->add('accessorys', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new LocationBikeAccessoryType(),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'allow_delete' => true,
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * Set default options.
     *
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\LocationBike',
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Returns form name.
     *
     * @return string form name
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'location_bike';
    }
}
```

And this one:

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

/**
 * LocationBikeAccessory form.
 */
class LocationBikeAccessoryType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * Build form.
     *
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('accessory', null, array('required' => true))
            ->add('price', 'sylius_money', array('required' => true))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * Set default options.
     *
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\LocationBikeAccessory',
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Returns form name.
     *
     * @return string form name
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'location_bike_accessory';
    }
}
```

When I submit the form I get the following error:

**Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, null given**

The issue only seems to be when I try to add a new item by submitting the form. If I add an item in the controller it will save just fine. Updating them with the form also works ok.

Edit with stacktrace:

```
[1] Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, null given
at n/a
    in /var/www/html/bimbim/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php line 2445

at Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler->handleError('2', 'spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, null given', '/var/www/html/bimbim/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php', '2445', array('entity' => null))
    in  line 

at spl_object_hash(null)
    in /var/www/html/bimbim/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php line 2445

at Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->cancelOrphanRemoval(null)
    in /var/www/html/bimbim/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/PersistentCollection.php line 475

at Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection->set('0', null)
    in /var/www/html/bimbim/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/PersistentCollection.php line 522

at Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection->offsetSet('0', null)
    in /var/www/html/bimbim/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.php line 219

at Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor->readPropertiesUntil(object(PersistentCollection), object(PropertyPath), '1', true)
    in /var/www/html/bimbim/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.php line 58

at Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor->getValue(object(PersistentCollection), object(PropertyPath))
    in /var/www/html/bimbim/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/DataMapper/PropertyPathMapper.php line 57

at Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataMapper\PropertyPathMapper->mapDataToForms(object(PersistentCollection), object(RecursiveIteratorIterator))
    in /var/www/html/bimbim/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php line 921

at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->add('0', object(LocationBikeAccessoryType), array('property_path' => '[0]', 'block_name' => 'entry'))
    in /var/www/html/bimbim/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/EventListener/ResizeFormListener.php line 128

at Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\EventListener\ResizeFormListener->preSubmit(object(FormEvent), 'form.pre_bind', object(EventDispatcher))
    in  line 

at call_user_func(array(object(ResizeFormListener), 'preSubmit'), object(FormEvent), 'form.pre_bind', object(EventDispatcher))
    in /var/www/html/bimbim/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 1949

at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(array(array(object(BindRequestListener), 'preBind'), array(object(TrimListener), 'preSubmit'), array(object(CsrfValidationListener), 'preSubmit'), array(object(ResizeFormListener), 'preSubmit')), 'form.pre_bind', object(FormEvent))
    in /var/www/html/bimbim/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 1882

at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch('form.pre_bind', object(FormEvent))
    in /var/www/html/bimbim/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/ImmutableEventDispatcher.php line 43

at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ImmutableEventDispatcher->dispatch('form.pre_bind', object(FormEvent))
    in /var/www/html/bimbim/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php line 551

at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->submit(array(array('accessory' => '2', 'price' => '5')), true)
    in /var/www/html/bimbim/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php line 572

at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->submit(array('bike' => '6', 'translations' => array('en' => array('description' => '', 'promo' => ''), 'nl' => array('description' => 'fdg', 'promo' => 'fg')), 'price_1_hour' => '', 'price_2_hour' => '5,00', 'price_4_hour' => '', 'price_24_hour' => '', 'price_48_hour' => '', 'price_72_hour' => '', 'price_96_hour' => '', 'price_120_hour' => '', 'price_144_hour' => '', 'price_168_hour' => '', 'available' => '1', 'deposit' => '0,00', 'specifications' => array(array('description' => 'dsf'), array('description' => 'dfg')), 'accessorys' => array(array('accessory' => '2', 'price' => '5')), '_token' => 'G55-UP3byjQlrVFw9FLXsfoGzH4Zn8bixv8gWPTLRg0', 'imageFile' => array('file' => null)), true)
    in /var/www/html/bimbim/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/HttpFoundation/HttpFoundationRequestHandler.php line 116

at Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\HttpFoundation\HttpFoundationRequestHandler->handleRequest(object(Form), object(Request))
    in /var/www/html/bimbim/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php line 498

at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->handleRequest(object(Request))
    in /var/www/html/bimbim/src/AppBundle/Controller/Admin/LocationController.php line 284

at AppBundle\Controller\Admin\LocationController->editBikeAction(object(Location), object(LocationBike), object(Request))
    in  line 

at call_user_func_array(array(object(LocationController), 'editBikeAction'), array(object(Location), object(LocationBike), object(Request)))
    in /var/www/html/bimbim/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3054

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1')
    in /var/www/html/bimbim/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3016

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
    in /var/www/html/bimbim/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3165

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
    in /var/www/html/bimbim/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2406

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
    in /var/www/html/bimbim/web/app_dev.php line 28
```

Comment: Not related to your problem, but the plural of accessory is accessories, not accessorys

Comment: @CarlosGranados You are right! I used accessories before, but I thought this might cause issues with the magic getter en setter methods.

Answer (score 1):

What version of symfony are you using? I had this problem and it was a bug in symfony -- https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/16090

I was using 2.7.4, but others reported the bug in 2.6 and earlier 2.7.* releases. Upgrading to Symfony 2.7.6 fixed the issue for me.

Comment: i had symfony 2.7.6 now. Upgrade Symfony can solved this issue. thanks Paul :)

Answer (score 0):

```
->add('price', 'sylius_money', array('required' => true))
```

replace by

```
->add('price', 'money', array('required' => true))
```

[Field Type Money](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/money.html)

And you can't add entity as null type
 Set

```
->add('accessory', 'entity',....) #Optional QueryBuilder function
```

Comment: hi @rommct thanks for your input! sylius_money type is part of the sylius money bundle I am using in my application. https://packagist.org/packages/sylius/money-bundle . If you set field type as null symfony will autoguess the field type. I have changed the code to your suggestions to double check: `->add('accessory', 'entity', array('required' => true, 'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Accessory'))
            ->add('price', 'money', array('required' => true))` Sadly I still get the same error. Any other ideas are very much welcome!